# how to change the colour of bottom navigation bar in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, imageview

[image]

In `themes.xml` when I add

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
```

the icon in red circle will also change to white in colour,how can I change the colour back to grey ?

Here is my code in `themes.xml`

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.CardHolderapp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/blue_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/blue_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor"> @android:color/transparent</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->


        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">
            true
        </item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white
        </item>

        <item name="android:nav">@color/white
        </item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

How to change the colour of bottom selection bar in android studio?

Comment: Is that possible only make changes in themes.xml?

Comment: Can you share desire output that you wanted??

Comment: @oscar you can change theme of bottom navigation menu using theme overlay

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new theme for bottom navigation menu in `styles`

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/Widget.App.BottomNavigationView</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.BottomNavigationView</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/COLOR_1</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/COLOR_2</item>
</style>
```

for more details refer [here](https://m2.material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android#bottom-navigation-bar)